# boolean declaration for a template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, boolean

My datatype is vertex V and I am using it as a template.

```
vector<Vertex*>* Graph::path(Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2)
{
Vertex* temp;
queue<Vertex*>* q;
q->push(v1);
bool *visited = new bool[v1];
}
```

The last line is showing error asking to input integral arguments only. How to improve??

Comment: q is a pointer to a queue, not an instance of Queue. Please instance a queue!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot enter pointer in `new bool[v1]` - for assignment. you need an integer value (like 3,4, etc.) or an lvalue which has an appropriate integer rvalue e.g. `int c= 5; int s[] = new int[c];`. This is pretty simply syntanctical code of conduct.

Comment: I want to make a pointer to set visited for my vertex. How can I do it without defining a new function

Comment: @YashJain       You have to understand this - your `v1` and `v2` are `Vertex` object pointers, it's not even an `int` pointer. To do `bool* visited = new bool[v1]` you must have v1 as an `int`. For example, if you had v1 = 5, it would have worked. Even if you had v1 as a pointer pointing to an integer value e.g. `int *v1 = 5`, you could have used `bool *visited = new bool[*v1]` where *v1 would be the value pointed to by v1 (i.e. 5). I don't know how much you know about pointeres in C/C++. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "Set visited for my Vertex". How are you using `*visited`?